# Is it possible to get open graph like to work with Master Pages and dynamic content?

Tags: dynamic-programming, facebook-opengraph

I have tried to get the open graph like to work with Master Pages and dynamic content in my asp.net project to no avail.  I have ads that people post with images and ad information maintained in my database.  Am I correct that the open graph objects are not a fit for a dynamic environment?

Answer (score 0):

Not at all, your master page can certainly be programmed to dynamically insert the correct values for the og: tags.

Comment: Which I tried.  I have one set of OG tags in my Master Page and I dynamically insert an image and a description.  The post to face book would not use the dynamically supplied OG tags.  Do you know of any examples that could help me?

Comment: Here's a .Net style example for the og:image tag dynamically rendered in the master page `<meta property="og:image" content="<%=GetImageUrlFor(Request.Url)%>" />`

Comment: I have not been able to write the function: GetImageUrlFor(Request.Url)  I am in ASP.Net/C#

Comment: Here's what the linter sees: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgigipage.com%2FSecure%2FViewGiGiAds.aspx%3FAdId%3D17

Comment: Your GetImageUrlFor() function should be a simple switch statement that returns a string.  Now that you've shared you have AdId as a parameter, you can use that instead of the Request.Url

Comment: Thank you for the help, it kept me from giving up. I finally went with loading the meta tags in the Page_Init. Worked like a charm.

Comment: I appreciated the assurance that it was possible to do what I wanted,  so instead of giving up I kept at it, and glad I did.  Thanks!